# UITextView text - animate text from top to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextview

I am using a `UITextView`. I want to autoscroll the textview's text with animation from top to bottom for one time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should animate the `UITextView`'s `contentOffset` property.

**Objective-C**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:{duration} animations:^{
    [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height)];
}]
```

**Swift**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: {duration}) {
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.height), animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(textView.text.length > 0 ) {
    NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1);
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Swift:**

```
let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.characters.count - 1, 0)
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

**Objective C:**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1);
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
```